# what this means 'neq' in magento2

Tags: magento2, collection, filter, order-collection

can someone explain for me the this attribute used in array?

```
$order = $this->createObject(Order::class)
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
                    ->addFieldToFilter('status',array('neq' => 'canceled'));
```

what 'naq' => 'canceled'?

Answer (score 2):

In this

```
 ->addFieldToFilter('status',array('neq' => 'canceled'));
```

Here status is in array like: pending, success, canceled

So **neq** means status should **not equal** to canceled

neq acts as '!=' for the sql query in magento.
Example - Select * from table where column != '1';

Answer (score 0):

**neq means Not Equals - neq**

**Example:**

```
$itemList->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('neq' => 'orderId'));
```